# how can I create an array of stdobj in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

In laravel the get() method over the DB returns an array of stdObjs,
for example this one:

```
$designers = DB::table('designers')->get();
```

Will return all designers from the designers table as an array of stdObj.

Now I want to manually create an array of stdObjs using something like this:

```
public function index()
    {

        $id = Auth::id();

        $user = User::find($id);

        foreach ($user->owned_item as $i) {          

                $result = new \stdClass(); 
                $result->type => $i->Item_type->type,
                $result->color => $i->Item_color->color


        }
```

obviously that code will overwrite the $result obj at every cycle, the question is, how do I create an array of all the stdobjs I need?

Comment: Why do you use a framework when you do not know basic PHP?

Comment: I'm learning, I'm sorry if you feel angry about it. thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: No offence, but I mean if you are learning please learn the basics first. It will make your life easier when you start using a framework.

Comment: And you can start here http://www.phptherightway.com/ or here http://daylerees.com/php-pandas/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign them to an array before the loop execution ends for each item.

```
$objs = [];

foreach (...) {
    $obj = new \stdClass();

    ...

    $objs[] = $obj;
}
```

After the loop the `$objs` variable contains an array containing the objects created inside the foreach loop.

EDIT: if you want to set specific array keys for each object, you can use

```
$objs[$key_here] = $obj;
```

when inserting the objects to the array. `$key_here` should be a string or an integer.

Comment: yes! it worked! thanks, I couldn't figure out how exactly this should be done